# Symfony 2: Is there a difference between repository defined as a service vs repository injected with expression?

Tags: symfony

I can define repository as a service:

```
<service id="books_repository" class="MyApp\BooksBundle\Repository\BooksRepository">
    <factory service="doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" method="getRepository"/>
    <argument>MyApp\BooksBundle\Entity\BookEntity</argument>
</service>
```

and then inject:

```
<service id="books_service" class="MyApp\BooksBundle\Service\BooksService">
    <argument type="service" id="books_repository"/>
</service>
```

But I can also use expression argument:

```
<service id="books_service" class="MyApp\BooksBundle\Service\BooksService">
    <argument type="expression">service('doctrine').getManager('default').getRepository('MyApp\BooksBundle\Repository\BooksRepository')</argument>
</service>
```

Are there any reasons I should prefer one solution over the other one? Are they functionally equivalent?

Comment: They are functionality equivalent.  Some folks feel that writing a little program (aka expression) inside a configuration file is going a bit too far.  But if your are comfortable with expressions and feel you can understand them when you come back in six months to make a change then either way is fine.

Comment: The only advantage I see with the second method is if the expression is executed at the creation of the service. If it work like this, you could evade circular references. But this has to be confirmed. Otherwise IMO you should prefer the first method because it's way far clearer.